# do-while loop is not constantly working

Tags: java

does anybody see wrong code here ?? i'd like to see do-while is working constantly as long as condition is not satisfied but it is certainly not. please tell me which part of code ruins my expected result?

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item item;
    String itemName;
    double itemPrice;
    int quantity;
    String keepShopping;
    double total = 0.0;
    DecimalFormat m = new DecimalFormat("######,##");
    do {
        System.out.print ("Enter the name of the item: ");
        itemName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter the unit price: ");
        itemPrice = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.print ("Enter the quantity: ");
        quantity = scan.nextInt();

        item = new Item(itemName,itemPrice,quantity);
        cart.add(item);
        total +=itemPrice*quantity;

        System.out.println ("Continue shopping (y/n)? ");
        keepShopping = scan.nextLine();

    } while (keepShopping.equals("y"));

    for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(cart.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println("Total price: " + m.format(total));
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] and tell us what input you're using.

Comment: Hint: print out `keepShopping` after you've read it. I suspect the value isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: @user307610 I'm guessing your have extra spaces or something causing the value to not equal "y".  Try calling a trim on the keepShopping.

Comment: `nextInt()` does **not** consume any characters following the integer value, so the CRLF after it is still in the buffer and is read by the `nextLine()` call, meaning that `keepShopping` is always a blank string (or whatever was typed after the quantity value on the same line).

Answer (score 2):

`nextInt()` does **not** consume any characters following the integer value, so the `CR LF` after it is still in the buffer and is read by the `nextLine()` call, meaning that `keepShopping` is always a blank string (or whatever was typed after the quantity value on the same line).

Your code is also calling `nextDouble()` and `nextInt()` without first calling the corresponding `hasNextDouble()` and `hasNextInt()` methods, so if you type something wrong, the program will crash and burn. Very common flaw in the use of `Scanner`.